# Accessing Nested Model in Form in Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested

I have two models. A Bill and an Account.

Account belongs_to Bill.  Bill has_many accounts.

I can create the Bill and Account models in rails console.

I thought I could assign the account model to a Bill in Rails console, such as myBill.account = myAccount, but this does not work.  Can this be done in Rails console ?

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bill
end

class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :accounts
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You then need to do

```
myAccount.bills << myBill
```